# Draw an Angle and fill it with gradient colors

Tags: ios, core-graphics, quartz-2d, drawrect, radial-gradients

I'm making a custom control and it was fine til my client says "I want it with gradients".
So here I am.
I need to draw an angle and fill it with gradient color. My previous code was this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.center.x, self.center.y);
CGContextAddArc(context, self.center.x, self.center.y, radius, radians(180), radians(minValue - 180), 0);
CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, gray);
CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```

With the CGContextAddArc() function I can draw my angle and paint it with CGContextSetFillColorWithColor() function, then close the path and *voilá*. But now I need to painted with gradients.
I know that maybe I should use CGContextDrawRadialGradient, but don't know how to use it with an arc.
I've been tried to figured out this with other question in StackOVerFlow and reading the doc, but I just can't get it.

Comment: Have you read the [Gradients chapter of the Quartz 2D Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_shadings/dq_shadings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH207-TPXREF101)?  Did you have trouble understanding it?  Do you need something other than a `CGGradient`?

Comment: Also, if you need to fill a shape using a `CGGradient`, you need to clip the context to the shape.  See [Clip the Context](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_shadings/dq_shadings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH207-BBCBCJAE) in the Quartz 2D Programming Guide.

Comment: @robmayoff Yes, I had read it. Specially the part of "Using a CGGradient Object", but as you said, am having problems understanding it. In fact I tried an answer of you (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783114/draw-outer-half-circle-with-gradient-using-core-graphics-in-ios) but I just can´t get it...

Comment: Provide a 50 point bounty for the exact code and surely someone will do it.