# Custom Drawing for iOS Control

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I've received a design for a new feature and would like tome tips or advice on where to begin for implementing this functionality.

[image]

Ideally there is also one for audio input that has to change in regards to the audio input sensitivity. So ideally this graph would need to animate in real time. I've looked that this post which seems somewhat helpful:

[Draw segments from a circle or donut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866179/draw-segments-from-a-circle-or-donut)

But would like some feedback or tips/ ideas to see if there is a better way to achieve this.

Comment: The link you give is a good start, give it a try and come back with specifics if you have problems.

Comment: As Wain said, the link is good. You will be working a lot with paths.