# Subview is not displaying the drawing view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to draw an arc similar to this [Draw segments from a circle or donut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866179/draw-segments-from-a-circle-or-donut). If I add it on `viewDidLoad` then it works but when I am waiting for an API call and then trying to add in a `reload` Method subviews are not added. Any idea?

Thanks in advance!!!

```
override func reloadData() {
   self.drawCircle()
}

func drawCircle() {
        let maxArcAngle = (360 - spacingInDegree*totalLevelsRequired) / totalLevelsRequired
        var previousStartAngle = 0
        var previousEndAngle = 360-maxArcAngle
        if let rating = userRating {
            for _ in  1...totalLevelsRequired {
                let vi = MView(frame: CGRect(x:16.0,y:12.0,width:40.0,height:40.0))
                print(previousStartAngle)
                print(previousEndAngle)
                previousStartAngle = previousEndAngle - spacingInDegree
                previousEndAngle = previousStartAngle - maxArcAngle
                vi.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                addSubview(vi)

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: try `DispathQueue.main` to update UI

Comment: Did you draw it on main thread when waiting API call?

Comment: As @WeiJay said you are probably on a background thread and need to run on the main thread to make UI changes.

Comment: Yes, I am calling on main thread. But I am releading the UI once I get API response. Other UI works fine. Exact the once which is drew is not showing

Comment: Can you provide code for fetching data and drawing?

Comment: @Bhoomi edited the post. Using this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43481532/1099453 for drawing circle