# Draw radial gradient from red to blue

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgcontext, radial-gradients

I need to draw a circle with a gradient that starts with red and ends with blue. It should look like [this one](http://abload.de/image.php?img=gradient2ros5s.png)

How to create such circle is explained [here](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/how-to-build-a-custom-control-in-ios/). But I have no idea how to draw such gradient. The problem is that the start color and end color are mixed.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second image, as @Putz1103 said, is just a linear gradient with a mask.

But what you are trying to do (as the first image suggests) is an angle gradient, not a circular gradient.

Here is an image of the three gradients with the same colors: linear, radial, angle:
[image]

Unfortunately CoreGraphics doesn't provide a way to create an angle gradient. But you could fake it in another way, like drawing small shapes with different colors around a circle. Here is how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12775798/942420