# Using UIColor(patternImage:) for UIView's tintColor?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uisegmentedcontrol, uicolor

I am using a `UISegmentControl` and am trying to give each segment's view a custom `UIColor`. This has been easy to do for solid colors. I simply do:

```
providerSegmentedControl.subviews[1].tintColor = UIColor.red
```

And the segment at index 1 will now be tinted with the color red.

However, I am trying to add a gradient for the `tintColor` of one of my segment's `UIView`. I have an image in my assets called "AppleMusicGradient" that looks like this:
[image]

I am trying to create a `UIColor` from this image using `UIColor(patternImage:)`. The code looks like this:

```
//UIImage.resize is a UIImage extension function that simply resizes a UIImage to the given CGRect
let image = UIImage(named: "AppleMusicGradient")!.resize(targetSize: providerSegmentedControl.subviews[2].frame.size)
providerSegmentedControl.subviews[2].tintColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
```

However, this method seems to only be partially working. When the given segment is selected, this gradient isn't visible at all. And when the given segment is unselected, the gradient is only visible on the label inside of the segment, i.e. the border normally seem is not present.

[image]

See the "Apple Music" segment.

Comment: Say David - unrelated to your question.  When you need a gradient like this.  A REALLY good thing is to just ........ make it, rather than using a prepared PNG.  (There are two important reasons (1) massive space saving (2) getting exact, awesome, ultimate resolution on every device.)  How to:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47760444/294884   Hope it's of interest

Comment: @Fattie thanks for the recommendation. The reason I am avoiding using a `CALayer` for the gradient is that I am not sure how I would could get a similar effect for a `UISegmentedControl` subview using a `CALayer`. i.e. I can set the `tintColor` using a `UIImage`, not sure I could say the same for `CALayer`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution feels a little "hacky" but I believe this may be what you are looking for.

```
@IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.updateGradientBackground()
}

private func updateGradientBackground() {
    let sortedViews = segmentedControl.subviews.sorted( by: { $0.frame.origin.x < $1.frame.origin.x } )
    for (index, view) in sortedViews.enumerated() {
        if index == segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "7Wk4B")!)
            view.tintColor = UIColor.clear
            let titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
            UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(titleTextAttributes, for: .selected)
            } else {
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            view.tintColor = UIColor.blue
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func segmentedControllerTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    self.updateGradientBackground()
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about maybe having to call something every time the segment changed. Thanks. I'll try this out and let you know how it works.

Comment: Yes be sure your segmented control is hooked up to both the IBOutlet and the IBAction.

Comment: unfortunately, I couldn't quite get this to work. For one thing, when setting the subview's `backgroundColor` and then calling the `UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes()`, the text of the individual segments wouldn't actually change.

Comment: I ran this on my end, and it seemed to change when selected. Does that background change to the gradient at least?

Comment: The background did change to gradient, fortunately. Not sure why text isn't updating color on my end.